# How to get variable value of one method of a class into another class

Tags: java, variables

How can I get value of local `a` variable defined in `method1` function of `ABC` class from `XYZ` class ?

```
class ABC {
  static method1() {
  int a = 1;
  }
}

class XYZ {
  System.out.print(method1.a)
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Add code that you've tried, any documentation you've relied on, that looks like you've tried to fix a problem and failed. Your question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to get a value from a variable inside a method if it does not return this value as a result of the method. If a variable is defined inside a method, it is created at the beginning of the method and destroyed at the end. If you want to use the class variable, then define it inside the class.

```
    class ABC {
    public static int a = 1;
    ...methods...
    }
    
    class XYZ {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ABC.a);
    }
```

Or this way:

```
class ABC {
  public static int getValue() {
  int a = 1;
  return a;
  }
}

class XYZ {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(ABC.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can create an Interface that will implement by the child's class.

```java
interface ABC {
    public static int a = 1;
}

class XYZ implements ABC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```